# Project Server 2012 Setup Claims there is a Previous Version - it's not

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, windows-server-2012, team-foundation-server, microsoft-project

I have set up a test environment with this software on the Server:

- Windows Server 2012 Standard
- SQL Server 2012
- SharePoint Server 2012 Enterprise
- Language Pack for the SharePoint Server
- Team Foundation Server 2012

Now I want to install Project Server 2012 additionally.

But the installer tells me there is a previous Version of Project already installed on the server. I uninstalled the language pack (which is also for Project) but it did not help.

Using a Snapshot from the time before installing TFS and the Language Pack, the Installation works flawlessly.

I could not imagine, the TFS Setup is in charge, because the setup guides also install TFS before Project Server. But what could cause this issue and how to get around?

Comment: Have you rebooted the server after installing TFS?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also installed all Updates an restarted again.

Comment: What happens if you install TFS after Project?

Comment: That may be possible, but I really want to preserve the actual config, data and Setup. It's our reference for other installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled TFS, SharePoint and the Language Pack in different orders, but at no point I have been able to install the Project Server, so I have to go back to the snapshot before the TFS Installation.